# Error while trying to run a datomic + clojure project

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, cloud, datomic

I'm trying to connect to a datomic cloud server that I configured inside EC2, but my clojure project keeps returning this error `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Expected string for :query-group {:cognitect.anomalies/category :cognitect.anomalies/incorrect, :cognitect.anomalies/message "Expected string for :query-group"`. I found this same error inside datomic cloud documentation (https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/troubleshooting.html), but it doesn't helped me, because I'm passing all the params that are required (server-type, region, system, endpoint and proxy port). Can somebody help me to find out what this error means and a workaround for it?